# Is there a way to load assets as an idle task when launching a tkinter app?

Tags: python, tkinter, assets

Sorry if the title isn't very clear but here is my problem: I am trying to build a tkinter application but when I launch it (wether it is from the command line or as a .exe file), you can see for a short period of time the blank window generated by the tk.Tk() function, and only then the assets are placed on the window.

What I would like to do however is to load the assets on the window before the user can see it. If I'm not being quite clear, please excuse me and of course I am willing to give further explanations on my issue.

Here is the code used when lauching the app:

```
from classes.mainMenu import MainMenu
from classes.log import Log
from tkinter import *
import os
import json
import datetime



class GUI():

    ### Constructors Region

    def __init__(self):

        # Creation of the window

        self.root = Tk()
        self.width = 1080
        self.height = 720

        self.root.title("GeoDataProcessing")
        self.root.iconbitmap('assets/Logo.ico')
        self.root.geometry(f'{self.width}x{self.height}+{int((self.root.winfo_screenwidth() - self.width) / 2)}+{- 50 + int((self.root.winfo_screenheight() - self.height) / 2)}')
        self.root.minsize(1080, 720)
        self.root.config(bg = 'white')      

        # Style attributes

        self.colorFont = '#3DC2F1'
        self.bg = 'white'
        self.buttonFont = ('Arial', 13)


        # Assets loading

        self.background = 0
        self.bannerBackground = 0

        self.loadAssets()


        # Protocols

        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.closeApp)

        # Others

        self.currentDirectory = os.getcwd()


        # Display of the background

        self.backgroundLabel = Label(self.root, image = self.background)
        self.backgroundLabel.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1) 

        self.version = "0.3.1"
        self.author = "Paul Wassermann"

        self.authorLabel = Label(self.root, text = f"Author: {self.author}", font = ('Arial', 12), fg = self.colorFont, bg = self.bg, bd = 2, relief = RIDGE)
        self.authorLabel.place(relx = 0.02, rely = 0.95)

        self.versionLabel = Label(self.root, text = f"Version {self.version}", font = ('Arial', 12), fg = self.colorFont, bg = self.bg, bd = 2, relief = RIDGE)
        self.versionLabel.place(relx = 0.98, rely = 0.95, anchor = NE)

        self.mainMenu = MainMenu(self)

        self.display()



    ### Methods Region

    def loadAssets(self):

        try:
            self.background = PhotoImage(file = "assets/background.png")
            self.bannerBackground = PhotoImage(file = "assets/bannerBackground.png")

        except:
            Log().writeLogException(level = "error", message = "Un problème est survenu lors du chargement des éléments visuels.\nConsultez le log pour plus d'informations.")



    def display(self):

        try:
            # Creation of the banner

            self.bannerFrame = Frame(self.root, width = 1080, height = 720)

            # Creation of the canvas containing the banner background as well as the text banner

            self.bannerCanvas = Canvas(self.bannerFrame, width = 840, height = 420, bd = 2, relief = RIDGE)
            self.bannerCanvas.create_image(int(self.bannerCanvas.cget("width")) / 2, 100 + int(self.bannerCanvas.cget("height")) / 2, anchor = CENTER, image = self.bannerBackground)
            self.bannerCanvas.create_text(int(self.bannerCanvas.cget("width")) / 2, - 40 + int(self.bannerCanvas.cget("height")) / 2, anchor = CENTER, text = "Bienvenue sur GeoDataProcessing!", font = ("Arial Bold", 32), fill = self.bg)
            self.bannerCanvas.create_text(int(self.bannerCanvas.cget("width")) / 2, 40 + int(self.bannerCanvas.cget("height")) / 2, anchor = CENTER, text = "L'outil de traitement des données d'essais pressiométriques", font = ('Arial', 20), fill = self.bg)
            self.bannerCanvas.pack()

            # Creation of the button to launch the application

            self.startButton = Button(self.root, text = "Commencer", font = ('Arial', 15), bd = 2, relief = RAISED, fg = self.colorFont, bg = self.bg, activeforeground = self.colorFont, activebackground = self.bg, command = lambda: [self.hide(), self.mainMenu.display()])
            self.root.bind("<Return>", lambda e: [self.hide(), self.mainMenu.display()])
            self.startButton.pack(side = BOTTOM, pady = 50)
            
            # Display of the banner

            self.bannerFrame.pack(expand = 'yes')

        except:
            Log().writeLogException()


    def hide(self):

        try:
            self.bannerFrame.destroy()
            self.startButton.destroy()
            self.root.unbind("<Return>")

        except:
            Log().writeLogException()



    def closeApp(self):

        try:

            dump = {}

            for key in self.mainMenu.configurationMenu.parameters:

                if key == "Last connection":
                    dump[key] = f"{datetime.date.today()}"

                else:
                    dump[key] = self.mainMenu.configurationMenu.parameters[key].get()

            with open(f"{self.currentDirectory}/files/paramètres.txt", 'w') as file:
                json.dump(dump, file, sort_keys = True, indent = 4)

        except:
            Log().writeLogException()

        finally:
            self.root.quit()
```

If you wonder why I load the images in a separate function and not in the constructor, it is for the purpose of putting it in a `try..except` block.

Edit:
The code that actually lauches the app (in my main.py file):

```
from classes.tubeCalibration import TubeCalibration
from classes.airCalibration import AirCalibration
from classes.gui import GUI
from classes.log import Log



try:
    gui = GUI()

    gui.root.mainloop()
    

except:
    Log().writeLogException(level = "error", message = "Un problème est survenu lors de l'exécution de l'application.\nContactez le support ou consultez le log détaillé pour résoudre le problème.")
```

Comment: Have you tried using threading or multiprocessing yet?

Comment: You could try calling `loadAssets()` at the very beginning of the constructor, before the window is created.

Comment: If you suppress the display of a blank window, it's going to seem like _nothing_ is going on. Consider displaying a temporary label that says "loading assets..." or something similar.

Comment: @RandomDavis No I haven't tried that as I am not familiar with threading, I am still learning to code. However, if you could guide me a little on how to use threads to solve my problem, I wouldn't mind looking more into it!

Comment: @Wups Unfortunately I can't load images before the main window is created, otherwise I get "Runtime error: too early to create image"

Comment: @Martineau that would be a great solution if loading the assets took several seconds but it's a matter of less than a second

Comment: Pauuuuuuul: In that case it sounds like a non-problem.

Comment: it's impossible for the window to appear before `mainloop` runs, or before you call `update` or `update_idletasks` no matter how long it takes to load the assets. You don't seem to have posted all your code, is it possible you're calling `update` or `update_idletasks` at some point?

Comment: @BryanOakley You're right, I'm calling "mainloop" in a different file in which I instantiate my GUI class, but at this point I don't call "update" or "update_idletasks"

Comment: @Martineau It is a problem for I am trying to provide a clean application. When you launch a software, you can see the pointer of the mouse turn into a spinning circle showing that it is loading, worst case. I really don't like the fact that the user can see the tkinter window being resized (to the size defined in the code) and the assets appearing

Comment: You may be able to call `root.withdraw()` to hide the window (and later make it visible later with `root.deiconify()`) — _if_ you can determine what is making the window appear before you want to see it.

Comment: @Martineau Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I was looking for!